# How to specify the location of R packages in foreach( ... , .packages="pkg") %dopar%

Tags: r, foreach

My "pkg" was installed somewhere else, how could I tell foreach where to find the package?

```
foreach(i = 1:2,.packages="pkg") %dopar% { ... }
```

This give me error message:

```
worker initialization failed: there is no package called 'pkg'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.libPaths()` function to set a library path in a running session.

Otherwise the startup files such as `~/.Renviron` can help, see the `?Startup`.

Lastly, if you use `foreach` to run of different machines, you need to take care of the library path on each of the machines.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach would be to distribute the `.libPaths` to all workers before you call `foreach`:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#setup parallel backend to use 8 processors
cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# pass libPath to workers, NOTE THIS LINE
clusterCall(cl, function(x) .libPaths(x), .libPaths())

parallelResults <- foreach(i = 1:42, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    # do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the libPaths inside the function

```
foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% { .libPaths("your_location_to_pkg") library("pkg") ... }
```