# Parallel processing in R ---there is no package called 'SNFtool'

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I want to run parallel code in R with the help of "parallel" package,and here is my code:

```
 library('SNFtool')
 foreach(i = 1,.packages=c('igraph','SNFtool')) %dopar%  calNMI(list2[[i]],list3[[i]])
```

The specific error I am getting is:

```
 Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
 worker initialization failed: there is no package called 'SNFtool'
```

However I do have the package 'SNFtool' and can load it from Rstudio and R from the command line . The issue seems to only be when running a script using parallel process.

Comment: is the package loaded within the script too?

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you want to do parralel processing in R, I recommend having a look into Revolution R open (Microsoft R Open). It uses improved BLAS libraries and multi cores.

Comment: do you have a non-standard library location? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412459/how-to-specify-the-location-of-r-packages-in-foreach-packages-pkg-do